# Restrict all docker outbound connections

Tags: docker

Is there a way to block my docker containers from making outbound connections? In development, I don't want my app container accidentally connection to my live server.

Fixing the credentials is in the works. I'm using docker in linux and mac but I'm looking for something that the OS doesn't matter.

Comment: Your prod credentials should never even come *close* to your dev environment. Solve that problem first, as it has the possibility of causing you very big problems.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/

Comment: Unplugging the network cable is OS-independent.

Comment: @JacobEvans I'm not seeing the info you see. I can create an internal network but that blocks incoming as well.

Comment: so put nginx or haproxy or...lb of choice in a network on both networks?

Answer (score 0):

use docker networking in host mode
v1

`net: "host"`

v2

`network_mode: "host"`

[Docker Compose File](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipv4-address-ipv6-address)